# How to handle a REST request?

Tags: rest

I found this site by searching some arguments about REST. I use to write PHP pages and represent data in JSON. I am a newbie about REST so there are a few things a don't understand. For example, i want to make a `GET www.mysite.com/people/1`request to shwo info about people "1". But i don't know how my server has to handle with this HTTP request. I thought a solution like that: make a `GET www.mysite.com/profile.php?action=get_user&id=1`and this PHP page, write `Location: www.mysite.com/people/1` to show the information required. But i am not sure about that. Could you help me please? Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The question is not really clear for me. You should provide more info about certain conditions you are going to use mentioned things in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need mod_rewrite or your server's URL rewriting capabilities to transform the incoming URL (`www.mysite.com/people/1`) to something that points to the backing php script, and that service needs to analyze the URL-parts that have become parameters now.

A thorough overview of the process can be found [here](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/building-a-restful-php-server-understanding-the-request), here are the very basic first steps:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ yourservice.php/$1 [L]
```

will rewrite

```
www.mysite.com/people/1
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/yourservice.php/people/1
```

Then,

```
explode('/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
```

will give yourservice.php access to the building blocks of the REST URL as an array, in your example, `people` and `1`.  From there you can decide what service to call, with what parameters.

Comment: I found difficulties to understand .htaccess sintax because i tried different things but i think i've got the right way in the end. Now i can go to the next step. Thank for your answer.